# How does Arduino IDE for OSX work without drivers?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, ftdi

My Arduino IDE works right out of the box without me having to install any USB to UART drivers. I know the Atmega16U2 on the UNO is acting as UART bridge, but this means that OSX recognizes it on a hardware level, which doesn't make sense since no drivers were installed - unless there is some sort of standard here that the Atmega16U2 implements?

The reason why I ask this is that I have a project where I want to connect an ATMega328p to a client mac which may not have access to 3rd party drivers, so having serial work natively with screen would be ideal. If the Arduino IDE can implement serial monitor without any additional drivers then it means I can too.

Does anyone know how this is implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds luke you want a CDC/ACM implementation.  Maybe you can meet your goal with just a 32u4, leonardo style?  There are lots of Arm parts with built in USB too.  Or you can do it the same way an Uno does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8.1 is the last version of any common desktop system that requires CDC/ACM (that is what the Arduino's USB port is) drivers.

OS X is based on BSD which, like Linux, has had CDC/ACM drivers built in since (pretty much) the dawn of time. It is only really Windows that has had the concept of drivers for anything that isn't vendor specific and/or complex (such as video cards, or devices that don't adhere to published standards).

Even Windows 10 now has the drivers for CDC/ACM built in (it's only taken Microsoft 20 years or so to catch up with the rest of the OS world).